# Converting string series to float list in python

Tags: python

I am quite new to programing so I hope this question is simple enough.

I need to know how to convert a string input of numbers separated by spaces on a single line:

```
5.2 5.6 5.3
```

and convert this to a float list

```
lsit = [5.2,5.6,5.3]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Is your variable really called `lsit` or is that a typo in the question? And if it was mant to be `list` then I should also add that you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name as it hides a built-in with the same name.

Answer (score 75):

Try a list comprehension:

```
s = '5.2 5.6 5.3'
floats = [float(x) for x in s.split()]
```

In Python 2.x it can also be done with map:

```
floats = map(float, s.split())
```

Note that in Python 3.x the second version returns a map object rather than a list. If you need a list you can convert it to a list with a call to `list`, or just use the list comprehension approach instead.

Comment: Just wanted to add that Decimal might be a better candidate for dealing with floating points. http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html

Comment: I'm getting the error "could not convert string to float" when trying to use this code